# JavaScript: How to initialise a class object with the new keyword in a mapper outside the class?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple console application with some tests. All I am testing is to check that the game starts with level 1. If the current level is 2 the next one should be 3 etc. The following code works fine but I wanted to move out the `gameMapper` function to its own file and import it within the `Game.js`.

Game.js

```js
export default class Game {
  constructor(level) {
    this.level = level;
  }

  static start = () => new Game(1);

  getNextLevel = () => gameMapper.find((g) => g.level === this.level).nextLevel;
}

const gameMapper = [
  { level: 1, nextLevel: new Game(2) },
  { level: 2, nextLevel: new Game(3) },
  { level: 3, nextLevel: new Game(4) },
];
```

sample.test.js

```js
import Game from '../src/Game';

describe('Test Game levels', () => {
  test('Game should start from level 1', () => {
    const game = Game.start();
    expect(game.level).toBe(1);
  });

  test('When game level is 2, the next level should be 3', () => {
    const game = Game.start().getNextLevel().getNextLevel();
    expect(game.level).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

The above code works completely fine. I have tried the following solutions but they did not seem to work for me. If anyone knows any better solutions please do let me know.

- Just moving out gameMapper function to it's own file. I get this error `TypeError: _Game.default is not a constructor`
- I then add the `init` function to the `Game` class which requires the level argument and initialises the Game class with that level. But I get another error as explained below.

gameMapper.js file

```js
import Game from './Game';

export const gameMapper = [
  { level: 1, nextLevel: Game.init(2) },
  { level: 2, nextLevel: Game.init(3) },
  { level: 3, nextLevel: Game.init(4) },
];
```

updated Game.js file

```js
import { gameMapper } from './gameMapper';

export default class Game {
  static init = (level) => new Game(level);

  getNextLevel = () => gameMapper.find((g) => g.level === this.level).nextLevel;

}
```

When I do the above where I move out the gameMapper and import it into the `Game.js` file I get the following error in `gameMapper.js`.

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')` at `{ level: 1, nextLevel: Game.init(2) }`

I am expecting that the tests should still pass when I move out the mapper.

Thank you all for your precious time :)

Comment: You've got a circular dependency. Do you really need `gameMapper` to be in a separate module? Do you need it at all, can't you just do `return new Game(this.level+1)`?

Comment: @Bergi I see that I am having a circular dependency, is there any other way that I can use to get around the circular dependency issue or do I have to have the `gameMapper` function within the `Game` class? I have simplified the code example here so I can't do what you suggested.

Comment: Either import the modules in the right order (*gameMapper.js* before *Game.js*), or move the `getNextLevel` into *gameMapper.js* (as an exported function instead of a method of `Game` instances). Or construct the `gameMapper` array lazily, possibly with dependency injection of the `Game` class.